# PHP Query to HTML radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql

i am a beginner in PHP.I have this query in my code.

```
$qsq = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT question_text FROM questions ");
```

I want to display the results of `$qsq` in radio buttons so that it can be selected.Then send the choices to another table with another query.Can someone help me with the coding please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the future, you might want to investigate PDO or mysqli with prepared statements. Sometimes this is outside the scope of tutorials, but something that shouldn't be ignored forever. You don't want to have a SQL injection incident. Research it sometime :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't tell anything about your table, so i cant give you anything exact (not that id necessarily want to, im just trying to give you broad strokes), but it sounds like you want a form with a group of radio buttons: one for each row.

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT id, question_text FROM questions");
echo "<form name='whatever' action='next.php' method='get'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
{
   echo "<input type='radio' name='choice' value='" . $row['id'] . "' /> ". $row['question_text'] . '<br />';
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit' /></form>";
```

Submitting this form will send to the url `next.php/choice=#` where you can retrieve the choice out of `$_GET` and do whatever you need to.

Comment: Scratch that first line ... the query was already run.  :)  However, I think the OP should certainly consider having a primary key (not obvious by the example) for the questions... having the full question/answer text in the radio button's value attribute probably isn't the best, and certainly not for normalizing the data in the database.

Comment: aah thanks.  i didnt notice that either, he certainly should SELECT id along with the text.  the distinct kind of throws me, he expects the table to have duplicate questions? im gonna ignore that so i dont need joins or extra logic to match id's to `question_text`

Comment: Hi,yes that's what i'm asking for.Thanks but there is some syntax error with the echo"<input type='radio ...>that line.Trying to figure it out now.

Comment: PHP syntax error?  or PHP runs fine and the resulting HTML is messed up?  it looks fine to me

Comment: what i initially called `name` should have been `question_text` (ive since changed it)  hopefully thats all it waS?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in line...

Comment: beats me.  i even ran a quick code pad to make sure, i dont see the error.  http://codepad.org/mhVfy8RO

Comment: ahahahaaaaha =P seriously tho glad it worked out.  y-chromosomes own-isomezzzzzzzz